# Mouse events on JPanel

Tags: java

i have mouselisteners on multiple jpanels. I need to detect if the mouse is pressed when it enters on a different jpanel than the one the event has started from. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Either listen on a `JPanel` that includes the others or see if using [*Drag and Drop*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) might suit your needs better.